# Strange Behavior with Threading and Timer

Tags: c#, multithreading, producer-consumer, blockingcollection

I explain my situation.

I have a producer 1 to N consumers pattern. I'm using blocking collections and everything is working well. Doing some test I noticed this strange behavior:

I was testing how long my manipulation of data took in my consumers.
I noticed this strange things, below you'll find the code cleaned of my manipulation and which produce the strange behavior.

I have 4 consumers for 1 producer.
For most of data, the Console doesn't print anything, because ts=0 (its under a tick) but randomly (between every 1 to 5sec) it plots something like this (not in this very specific order, but of the same kind):

```
10000
20001
10000
30002
10000
40003
10000
10000
```

It is of the order of 10,000 ticks so around 1ms. Always a number in the format (N)000(N-1)
Note that the BlockingCollection I consume is filled depending on some network events which occurred completely at random times. Nothing regular from here.

The timing is almost perfect, always a multiple of 10,000 ticks.

What could be behind this ? Thks !

```
    while(IsAlive)
    {
            DataToFieldMapping item;
            try
            {
                _CollectionToConsume.TryTake(out item, -1);
            }
            catch
            {
                item = null;
            }
            if (item != null)
            {
                    long ts = (DateTime.Now.Ticks - item.TimeStamp.Ticks);
                    if(ts>10)
                       Console.WriteLine(ts);
            }
     }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What's going on here is that `DateTime.Now` has a fairly limited precision.  It's not giving you the time to the nearest tick.  It is only updated every 10,000 ticks or so, which is why you generally see multiples of 10k ticks in your prints.

If you really want to get a better feel for the duration of those events, use the `StopWatch` class, which has a *much* higher precision.  That said, `StopWatch` is simply a diagnostic tool (hence why it's in the `Diagnostics` namespace).  You should only be using it to help you diagnose what's going on, and should be using it in production code.

On a side note, there really isn't any need to use a timer here at all.  It appears that you're creating several consumers that are polling the `BlockingCollection` for new content.  There is no reason to do this.  They can simply block until the collection has items.  (Hence the name, `BlockingCollection`.

The easiest way is for the consumers to simply do this:

```
foreach(var item in _CollectionToConsume.GetConsumingEnumerable())
   ProcessItem(item);
```

Then just run that code in a background thread.

Comment: Ok, Thks for the side note , i'll replace my while()/trytake with your loop.

Answer (score 1):

if you write the following and run, you'll see that ticks do not roll one to one, but rather in relatively large chunks b/c ticks resolution is actually much smaller.

```
for(int i =0; i< 100; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.Ticks);
}
```

Use `Stopwatch` class to measure performance as that one uses a high-resolution timer which is much more suitable for the purpose.